# How to open/browse an mbox file?

Tags: email, browser, apple-mail, mbox

Specifically an Apple Mail .mbox file. I'm looking for a way to browse the emails it contains short of just importing it back into Apple Mail and cluttering up my currents emails.

I don't mind having to convert the mbox file to something else if need be.

A command line tool is also fine (preferred even).

Many thanks if anyone can help!

Comment: Give Thunderbird a go.

Comment: I'm assuming it needs to be for/in OS X? Or would a windows or linux solution be fine?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

OS X, like most Unix and Linux variants, has the command-line [`mail` and `mailx`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mailx.1.html) clients.

You can see if they will read your `.mbox` file. They do use `mbox` as one of the filenames they handle.

```
mail -f ~/.mbox
```

Use the `x` command to exit without changing the file.

Comment: `mail` is good for plain-text messages, but cumbersome for HTML and outright useless for something with a lot of embedded graphics or heavy use of HTML layout mechanisms which do not render well in a terminal.

Comment: +1 for `x`. I used `q`, and that transferred the mail from `/var/mail/user` to `~/mbox`

Answer (score 4):

Berkeley MBOX is basically a plain-text format so you can view it simply with `less`, though you will need to understand SMTP and MIME to make sense of what you are looking at.  Every line which matches the regular expression `^From`  (with a space after the four alphabetics) is the beginning of a new message.  Modern email messages use various MIME transport encodings which can be anything between almost human-readable (`=?utf-8?Q?Like_this?=`) to completely oblique (base64).

You can use `csplit` on the same regex to split the file into individual messages, or use the `formail` utility which is part of the Procmail package with the `-s` option. The latter offers a number of options to enable various heuristics if the input file is not completely well-formed, etc.

For graphics-heavy email messages with potentially problematic contents (i.e. spam), I have occasionally spun up Thunderbird in a Virtualbox instance and made sure it has no access to the Internet, then imported the mailbox there for modern HTML etc rendering.  If a message requires images from an external server, you just get a placeholder if the image cannot be fetched.

Comment: +1 for `csplit`

Answer (score 1):

I might create a secondary user and import your file there... Easy-peasy browsing without cluttering up your account.