# how to open an mbox file with mailutils for local use?

Tags: command-line, email, email-client, mbox, mailutils

How do I open the `mbox` file for offline local usage?

Just looking to [browse](https://askubuntu.com/q/114063/847449) the messages with the mail command and expecting a menu listing the messages.

From the man pages, I didn't see an [explicit](https://superuser.com/q/448681/977796) command for this.

From ~/mail I can run:

mail -f bar

and get the expected list of e-mails.  Here, bar is like "sent-mail" which is from alpine (old pine mail).  That works as expected.

But I can't seem to get the same result on this mbox file.

****alpine doesn't use mbox*******

Comment: Does `mail.mailutils -f mbox` work ?